# Is it possible to run a script on subfolders

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a code that renames multiple files in Google Drive (taken from [Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145769/how-to-create-find-and-replace-function-for-google-drive-file-names-with-google/162421#162421)) and here is the content

```
function rename() {

  var folderid = "<<insert your folder ID>>"
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)

  var myfiles = folder.getFiles();

  while (myfiles.hasNext()) { 
  
    var myfile = myfiles.next();   
    var myname = myfile.getName();
    var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();

    var indexOfFirst = ftype.indexOf(mimetype);


var fname = myname.replace("source", "change");
myfile.setName(fname);    
  } 
  return false;
}
```

My problem is that it only works on the root folder and not on subfolders
Is there a solution to allow code to run on subfolders?

Comment: You can use recursion to walk through the  subfolders

Comment: How do you make such a thing happen?

Comment: There are several answers on recursion in SO do some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you want it to run on all files in subfolders of the original folder.  If you also want to run it on subfolders of those folders, and so on, you can use a recursive solution:

Use [`folder.getFolders()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfolders) to find the subfolders, then run the `rename` function on those folders:

```
function rename(folderId) { // Add the parameter here

  // var folderid = "<<insert your folder ID>>" // Remove this line
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)

  var myfiles = folder.getFiles();

  while (myfiles.hasNext()) { 
  
    var myfile = myfiles.next();   
    var myname = myfile.getName();
    var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();

    var indexOfFirst = ftype.indexOf(mimetype);


    var fname = myname.replace("source", "change");
    myfile.setName(fname);    
  } 

  // Add these lines to recursively apply the function to subfolders:
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) { 
    var subfolder = subfolders.next();
    rename(subfolder.getId()); // this calls the same function, but passes the subfolder id
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I did as you wrote and then I had a problem, the problem is that for some reason it takes a large amount of time.

Comment: What does "Add the parameter here" mean? What parameter is this?

Comment: I was just pointing out that I had made `folderId` a parameter of the function

Comment: If you have a large number of files and/or subfolders, it will take a long time.  You might speed it up by only calling `myfile.setName()` if  `fname` is different from `myname`.

Comment: Even after your improvement, it still only worked for me on the root folder before the time limit expired.
In my opinion a single GS can not include the whole drive.
I now have 2 questions. Question 1 Is it possible to work with GS independently and not through Google (perhaps with an API). Question 2 Is it possible to get the names of all the folders and create from each folder a custom script file for that folder. (I hope I understand that the text has been translated)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Question 1.  For Question 2, the answer is yes: you should post it as a separate question here on Stack Overflow to get a detailed answer.

Comment: I apologize for not speaking clearly, the reason is because I do not speak English and the text is being translated. I was going to ask in question 1 whether it is possible to do the action I do in Google Script in running my private site because Google has a time limit and my site has no time limit. (Sorry if I'm not clear, no need to try to figure out you can leave me unanswered).

Comment: Yes, you could do it via the Drive API.  But the setup/auth is more complicated.

Comment: I will give up the API because I am an amateur programmer