# Is it possible to get the names of all the folders and create from each folder a custom script file for that folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I made a code that renames multiple files in Google Drive (taken from [Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145769/how-to-create-find-and-replace-function-for-google-drive-file-names-with-google/162421#162421)) and here is the content

```
function renamejpgs() {

  /* 
  // A given Goiogle Drive folder contains jpg files.
  // The files have a consistent naming structure:
  // "AA123_y.jpg, where y is a single or multi-digit sequence number.
  //
  // The function renames the files by removing the third, fourth, fifth and sixth characters of the file name and substituting a single"underscore"
  // For example, "AA123_1.jpg" -> "AA_1.jpg"
  */
   
  // set the mime type/file type to be renamed
  var mimetype = 'image/jpeg';
  // get the folder ID; note the id is a string
  var folderid = "<<insert your folder ID>>"
  
  // getFoldersById = Gets a specific folders in the user's Drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)
 
  // get  files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
  var myfiles = folder.getFiles();

  // loop through files in this folder
  while (myfiles.hasNext()) { 
  
    var myfile = myfiles.next();   
    var myname = myfile.getName();
    var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();
    // find the next file that matches the mime type
    var indexOfFirst = ftype.indexOf(mimetype);

    if (indexOfFirst != -1){ 
      // the next file was an image
    
      // edit the file name
      var fname = myname.replace("123_", "_");
      // update the file name
      myfile.setName(fname);       
 
    } //end if
  } // end while loop through main folder
  
  return false;
}
```

My problem is that it only works on the root folder and not on subfolders
I tried to ask in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70793063/is-it-possible-to-run-a-script-on-subfolders) place if subfolders could be included and they helped me change the name there. But then there was a problem of a longer time than the Google limit.
My question is Is it possible to get the names of all the folders and create from each folder a custom script file for that folder in Google Drive

Comment: try adding a wait to it so it wont be running so long (like adding setTimeout in js)

Comment: If he does not work for a long time he will not change all the names. But in any case, answers of this kind should come to me in the second post. Here I asked a more specific question. Anyway thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My question is Is it possible to get the names of all the folders and create from each folder a custom script file for that folder in Google Drive`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? In your situation, how many files and folders in your Google Drive? Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: 1. It's ok not to know English I also do not know English (I speak Hebrew) 2. My question is how to produce a large amount of Google script files that each file will be compatible with one folder and rename in the same folder. I hope I understand because of the language

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand `how to produce a large amount of Google script file`. But I cannot understand `each file will be compatible with one folder and rename in the same folder`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, when you reply to the comment, when you add `@username` like `@tanaike`, I can notice your reply.

Comment: Thank you @tanaike for making the effort to understand me. I can not explain to you because the text is being translated. I will try a different wording. The matter is as follows. The first step is to obtain the ID of each folder within Google Drive. I currently have a text that contains for example 50 addresses. A second action is to create 50 functions each of which is similar to the function I wrote in the question with a slight change between them of ID. If you do not understand now I am really bad at it so I will ask another person who sees what I have written to write in his language.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had understood that you wanted to change the filenames. But from your replying, I noticed that my understanding was not correct. I apologize for this. In your question, about `The first step`, I understood that you want to retrieve 50 folders. Is my understanding correct? In this case, even when the number of folders is over 50, you want to retrieve 50 folders. Is my understanding correct? Unfortunately, I cannot understand `A second action`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @tanaike I will try one last time and after that I will give up (maybe you have already given up and you do not have to try to understand). I wanted to do everything in one command but it is not effective because it is over 6 minutes and there is a time limit. So I decided to give up a single command mode and run many commands. So I want to get an answer from the drive what the names of all the folders are and produce a lot of commands and each command is customized for a particular folder. And then I will execute each command individually.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to change the folder names of all folders in your Google Drive using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @tanaike Your understanding is correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you change the filename, can you provide the sample filenames before and after the filename?

Comment: @tanaike Thank you for replying. I'm not so familiar with Google Script it's just code I copied.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to prepare the sample script, it is required to know the sample filenames before and after the filename of the file, you want to change. So I asked about it.

Comment: @tanaike Thank you for replying. I'm not sure I understand what you mean but if you mean what name I change then that's the answer. Before replacement it is called 123_e.jpeg and after replacement it is called e.jpeg.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `Before replacement it is called 123_e.jpeg and after replacement it is called e.jpeg.`, in this case, do you want to change the filenames instead of the folder names? Or, `123_e.jpeg` is the folder name? And, when the filename of `123_e.jpeg` is changed to `e.jpeg`, do you want to search `123_e.jpeg`, and changed it to `e.jpeg`? When there are a lot of filenames, I cannot understand the logic for achieving your goal. I'm confusing your question. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @tanaike. I wrote e.jpeg but it's a mistake I should have written _e.jpeg

Comment: @tanaike My goal is not to rename folders but to rename files.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @tanaike Thank you for replying. I would very much like to explain well but apparently my English writing skills are poor. I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function renamejpgs() {

  /* 
  // A given Goiogle Drive folder contains jpg files.
  // The files have a consistent naming structure:
  // "AA123_y.jpg, where y is a single or multi-digit sequence number.
  //
  // The function renames the files by removing the third, fourth, fifth and sixth characters of the file name and substituting a single"underscore"
  // For example, "AA123_1.jpg" -> "AA_1.jpg"
  */
   
  // set the mime type/file type to be renamed
  var mimetype = 'image/jpeg';
  // get the folder ID; note the id is a string
  var folderid = "<<insert your folder ID>>"
  
  // getFoldersById = Gets a specific folders in the user's Drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)
 
  // get  files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
  var myfiles = folder.getFiles();

  // loop through files in this folder
  while (myfiles.hasNext()) { 
  
    var myfile = myfiles.next();   
    var myname = myfile.getName();
    var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();
    // find the next file that matches the mime type
    var indexOfFirst = ftype.indexOf(mimetype);
    Utilities.sleep(10);
    if (indexOfFirst != -1){ 
      // the next file was an image
    
      // edit the file name
      var fname = myname.replace("123_", "_");
      // update the file name
      myfile.setName(fname);       
 
    } //end if
  } // end while loop through main folder
  
  return false;
}
```

I believe this will help stop the code from timing out.

---

I added a sleep function to pause it and stop it from exhaustion.

---

This is my basis of research for using the sleep function: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116041/how-to-set-up-delays-in-google-apps-script

Comment: If he does not work for a long time he will not change all the names. But in any case, answers of this kind should come to me in the second post. Here I asked a more specific question. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this implementation, I've decided to use Drive API service on Apps Scripts in order to use the filter functionality (`q` parameter) of Drive API queries.

Given that, make sure to add Drive API on the service list on your Apps Scripts project.

The code below will "scan" for a file name that includes MATCH_PATTERN set on a given starting folder ID including sub-folders.

Make sure to customize the constants in the beginning to adapt to your use case.
The function main() is a sample start point for this script.

#### Sample Code:

```js
const MATCH_PATTERN = "[replace]"; //file name pattern to be renamed
const REPLACE_PATTERN = "[123456789]"; //pattern to replace MATCH_PATTERN from file name
const MIMETYPE_TARGET_FILES = "image/jpeg"; //mimetype of target files

function listFoldersIn(parentId = "root") {
  /**
   * Lists sub-folders in the user's Drive for a given folder ID.
   * Slightly modified script from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_folders
  */
  var query = '"'+ parentId +'" in parents and trashed = false and ' +
      'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"';
  var folders;
  var pageToken;

  var folderIdList = [];
  do {
    folders = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (folders.items && folders.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < folders.items.length; i++) {
        var folder = folders.items[i];
        folderIdList.push(folder.id);
      }
    }
    pageToken = folders.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  
  return folderIdList;
};

function listTargetFilesForParent(parentId = "root", mime = MIMETYPE_TARGET_FILES) {
  /**
   * Lists files on a given folder ID matching the MIME type set.
   * Slightly modified script from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_folders
  */
  var query = '"'+ parentId +'" in parents and trashed = false and ' +
      'mimeType = "'+ mime +'"';
  var files;
  var pageToken;

  var fileIdList = [];
  do {
    files = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (files.items && files.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.items.length; i++) {
        var file = files.items[i];
        fileIdList.push({title: file.title, id: file.id});
      }
    }
    pageToken = files.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  
  return fileIdList;
};

function renameFilesInFolders(folderList) {
  if (folderList.length > 0) { //if folder ID list provided is empty, exit method;
    for (folder of folderList) { //loop for folder ID list provided.
      //Fetch target files in current folder
      var filesList = listTargetFilesForParent(parentId = folder);

      renameTargetFiles(filesList); // Rename files if applicable;

      //Check for sub folders
      var subFolders = listFoldersIn(folder);
      if (subFolders.length > 0) { //It has subfolders?
        renameFilesInFolders(subFolders); //call this same method recursively
      } else { //if current folder does not have sub-folders, then do nothing and continue loop;
        continue;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function renameTargetFiles(filesList){
  for (file of filesList) { //loop through file list provided
    if (file.title.includes(MATCH_PATTERN)) { //is current file applicable to be renamed? In other words, does the current file name contain the MATCH_PATTERN?
      var newName = file.title.replace(MATCH_PATTERN, REPLACE_PATTERN); //replace MATCH_PATTERN from file name for REPLACE_PATTERN
      Drive.Files.patch({title: newName}, file.id); //Call Drive API patch to modify file name. 
    }
  }
}

function main() {
  /**
   * Make sure to set up constants in the beginning of this file to adapt to your use case
   * When calling renameFilesInFolders() without passing parameters, it will scan starting from the root of My Drive.
   * Passing an array of a single Drive Folder ID, sets the root level for the scan
   */ 

  renameFilesInFolders(["<STARTING_FOLDER_ID>"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the work invested but it does not work.

Comment: Can you share more details on how it failed?

Comment: I apologize for my excessive delay I just did not have time off and then I forgot. I have enabled the 'listFoldersIn' function and it does not define anything for me